# which is the correct why installing python-openssl on rpi getting error unable to locate package python-openssl

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I am trying to installing DHT22  getting the error 
E: unable to locate package python-openssl
Also same error on while installing different packages

sorry my bad english

Comment: correct way installing python-openssl on rpi getting error unable to locate package python-openssl

Comment: You should not be adding more info in the comments these details belong in your question (click edit)

Comment: root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-openssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is command will install it using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-openssl
```

Comment: root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-openssl                                                                                                           Reading package lists.. Done                                                                                              Building dependency tree                                                                                    Reading state information... Done                                                                           E: Unable to locate package python-openssl

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update first? What version of raspbian are you using?

Comment: Yes i done sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: AND WHAT VERSION OF RASPBIAN ARE YOU USING? ANSWERING HALF THE QUESTION DOESN"T HELP.

Comment: sorry     Linux raspberrypi 4.1.21+

Comment: No, Wheezy or Jessie
\

Comment: my version of raspbian 7 (Wheezy)

Comment: @Mr.Monster Assuming the apt-get update ran without issue, you have a problem with your sources list. I would suggest trying a fresh SD card and image.

Comment: can give me another option????

Comment: can i restore the Raspberry pi?? which way ?? Its possible....

Comment: Thanks@Steve                    i get answer    As suggested, I took a look at my raspbian /etc/apt/sources.list and it had this one line:
 deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main
I replaced it with the line 
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
Ran sudo-apt get update and all packages now load fine.